# POSIXct Strips Seconds from 12-hour Timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct

I'm trying to convert a 12-hour timestamp to a POSIXct object in R. For some reason it strips away the seconds after the conversion.

```
## timestamp
chk = '17-MAY-16 04.51.34.000000000 PM'

## convert
as.POSIXct(chk, format = '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%OS %p', tz = 'America/New_York')
[1] "2016-05-17 16:51:00 EDT"
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not strip the seconds.  It simply adheres to a default for *printing and formatting* which does *not* include subseconds.

Witness an example that

- actually has subsecond entries
- runs in a session with `options(digits.secs)` set correctly
- corrects one error you had in the format string

Demo:

```
R> options(digits.secs=6)    # important to tell R we want subsecs
R> input <- '17-MAY-16 04.51.34.123456 PM'
R> as.POSIXct(input, '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p', tz = 'America/New_York')
[1] "2016-05-17 16:51:34.123456 EDT"
R>
```

If we reset `digits.secs=0` it falls back to whole seconds only (which is after all a good default for many settings, though one may argue that `%0S` could override it...)

```
R> options(digits.secs=0)    # reset
R> as.POSIXct(input, '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p', tz = 'America/New_York')
[1] "2016-05-17 16:51:34 EDT"
R>
```

Also note the small change to the format string. Don't use both `%S` and `%OS`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was a mistake to use both `%S` and `%OS` in the formatting string. This solved my issue.

Comment: Well ... I actually have a package for those woes ;-)  [anytime](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) (but it has a _strong_ preference for `%Y` over `%y` for the usual reasons).